# Splitting an array of arbitrary size elements

Tags: python

I have a list of sentences which I read off an article, and I wish to group them in evenly sized (as much as possible) buckets of max N characters, with the extra complication of keeping the buckets roughly the same size, and the sentences unsplit.

I am using python and the naive approach I have in mind is to:

1. Iterate over the sentences and fill each bucket until it's full.
2. Go over the buckets iteratively and try to even them.

The second part is what I'm afraid isn't going to be as straightforward, and I wonder if there's a quick/smart way to achieve that?

Full example data would be too large here, but in a simpler form:
[[Sentence 1 with 30 words], [Sentence 1 with 3words][[Sentence 1 with 15 words][[Sentence 1 with 10 words], ...]

A bucket would be [sent1, sent 2...] of total character length the sum of the sentences.

And I would like to group into X buckets, were total sentences length in each bucket will be as much as evenly spread as possible, and must not pass a certain thredhold.

Comment: Please give example input/output.

Comment: get the string len ... find the factors of string len .. then it's up to you how many buckets you want if you want more buckets then divide my min factor , if you want less buckets divide it by max factor.

Comment: Guess that's a better term. I will update.

Comment: @rubmz please add the example

Comment: Added (something like) an example.

Comment: Do you know the number of buckets you want (X) or do you need it to be computed in such a way that the differences in size are minimized.  Also, your example repeats "Sentence 1" in every bucket and it also has 3 levels of list nesting which doesn't fit your explanations.  Can you make it an actual Python list with strings.

Comment: I can have as many buckets I want, just filled upto max size + have them filled as evenly as possible.

Comment: sounds like the knapsack problem?

Comment: @njzk2 or maybe modified text justification/word wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first step will compact the sentences into the lower groups (left) so the second step could perform an optimization by shifting sentences to the right.

Keep in mind that there will be a very large number of permutations of those sentence shiftings (which will grow exponentially with the number of sentences).

An easy way to implement this is to process a list of sentence lengths instead of sentences themselves.  You can group the actual sentences based on the length groupings when you're done.

**Test Data:**

```
sentences="""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""".split(". ")
sentences *=60              # 240 sentences
from random import shuffle
shuffle(sentences)
```

**Sentence length grouping**

```
SL = [len(s) for s in sentences]

bucketCount = 10
bucketSize  = max(max(SL),sum(SL)//(bucketCount-1)) # safe max bucket size

groups = []
for size in SL:
    if not groups or sum(groups[-1])+size>bucketSize:
        groups.append([size])
    else:
        groups[-1].append(size)

print(*groups,sep="\n")
[101, 122, 110, 106, 122, 101, 110, 101, 110, 101, 106, 101, 101, 106, 101, 110, 122, 106, 106, 101, 122, 122, 122, 110, 122, 110]
[110, 106, 110, 110, 101, 106, 122, 110, 106, 101, 101, 122, 106, 122, 122, 110, 122, 106, 122, 122, 106, 106, 122, 101, 122, 122]
[106, 122, 122, 101, 101, 110, 106, 110, 110, 101, 110, 110, 106, 106, 106, 106, 101, 122, 101, 110, 122, 122, 110, 110, 101, 122]
[106, 122, 101, 110, 106, 110, 122, 122, 110, 101, 122, 101, 110, 110, 122, 122, 106, 110, 101, 122, 101, 106, 106, 101, 101, 101]
[106, 110, 122, 101, 122, 110, 122, 122, 122, 110, 106, 101, 106, 106, 110, 106, 122, 106, 110, 106, 110, 101, 110, 110, 122, 122]
[110, 101, 110, 106, 101, 101, 110, 101, 110, 122, 122, 101, 106, 110, 110, 122, 110, 110, 122, 106, 110, 122, 106, 101, 101, 110]
[101, 101, 101, 106, 101, 106, 106, 101, 101, 122, 101, 122, 106, 122, 106, 110, 101, 122, 101, 110, 106, 106, 122, 122, 106, 106, 106]
[110, 101, 106, 106, 101, 101, 122, 106, 101, 122, 106, 101, 122, 110, 106, 106, 110, 122, 110, 110, 101, 101, 106, 110, 110, 106, 101]
[122, 101, 110, 122, 106, 122, 110, 101, 110, 101, 110, 122, 106, 106, 122, 106, 122, 110, 101, 101, 106, 106, 106, 101, 110, 110]
[122, 101, 110, 106]
```

*As you can see, the last group has a lot of room to shift into*

**Group Optimization**

Here is a "brute force" optimization function that explores the permutations of group member shiftings (to the right) and returns the optimal grouping.

*Note that this function's performance has a lot of room for improvements, I did not attempt to optimize the optimization function.*

```
# Recursive function that goes through shifting permutations    
def optimize(groups,bucketSize):
    if len(groups)==1: return groups
    optimal = groups
    minSum  = min(map(sum,groups))
    for i in reversed(range(1,len(groups))):
        if groups[i-1][-1]+sum(groups[i])<=bucketSize:
            oGroups = [g.copy() for g in groups]
            oGroups[i].insert(0,oGroups[i-1].pop(-1))
            oGroups[:i+1] = optimize(oGroups[:i+1],bucketSize)
            ms = min(map(sum,oGroups))
            if ms>minSum:
                minSum,optimal = ms,oGroups
    return optimal
            
optimal = optimize(groups,bucketSize)  # takes about a minute for 240 sentences  
        
bucketSize = max(map(sum,optimal)) # Effective bucket size                          
for g in optimal:
    print(sum(g),sum(g)-bucketSize,g)

2620 -80 [101, 122, 110, 106, 122, 101, 110, 101, 110, 101, 106, 101, 101, 106, 101, 110, 122, 106, 106, 101, 122, 122, 122, 110]
2681 -19 [122, 110, 110, 106, 110, 110, 101, 106, 122, 110, 106, 101, 101, 122, 106, 122, 122, 110, 122, 106, 122, 122, 106, 106]
2634 -66 [122, 101, 122, 122, 106, 122, 122, 101, 101, 110, 106, 110, 110, 101, 110, 110, 106, 106, 106, 106, 101, 122, 101, 110]
2700 0 [122, 122, 110, 110, 101, 122, 106, 122, 101, 110, 106, 110, 122, 122, 110, 101, 122, 101, 110, 110, 122, 122, 106, 110]
2621 -79 [101, 122, 101, 106, 106, 101, 101, 101, 106, 110, 122, 101, 122, 110, 122, 122, 122, 110, 106, 101, 106, 106, 110, 106]
2630 -70 [122, 106, 110, 106, 110, 101, 110, 110, 122, 122, 110, 101, 110, 106, 101, 101, 110, 101, 110, 122, 122, 101, 106, 110]
2599 -101 [110, 122, 110, 110, 122, 106, 110, 122, 106, 101, 101, 110, 101, 101, 101, 106, 101, 106, 106, 101, 101, 122, 101, 122]
2606 -94 [106, 122, 106, 110, 101, 122, 101, 110, 106, 106, 122, 122, 106, 106, 106, 110, 101, 106, 106, 101, 101, 122, 106, 101]
2643 -57 [122, 106, 101, 122, 110, 106, 106, 110, 122, 110, 110, 101, 101, 106, 110, 110, 106, 101, 122, 101, 110, 122, 106, 122]
2606 -94 [110, 101, 110, 101, 110, 122, 106, 106, 122, 106, 122, 110, 101, 101, 106, 106, 106, 101, 110, 110, 122, 101, 110, 106]
```

*The effective bucket size is 2700 and the largest difference in total sentence length is 101 characters (3.7%)*

**grouping actual sentences**

```
iSentence = iter(sentences)
sentenceGroups = [[next(iSentence) for _ in g] for g in optimal]
```

**[EDIT]**
I found a much faster way to perform the groupings by recursively finding the best split in two.  It is not always as perfectly optimal but it runs much faster.

```
def makeGroups(SL,buckets):
    if buckets == 1: return [SL]
    left = buckets//2            # left side buckets
    lSum = sum(SL)*left/buckets  # target sum for left side
    mid  = min(range(len(SL)),key=lambda i:abs(sum(SL[:i])-lSum))
    return makeGroups(SL[:mid],left)+makeGroups(SL[mid:],buckets-left)


def groupSentences(sentences,buckets):
    iS = iter(sentences)
    return [ [next(iS) for _ in g] for g in makeGroups([*map(len,sentences)]) ]
```

*This gives almost instantaneous results for 10,000 sentences (compared to my initial solutions that could take minutes for a mere 240 sentences)*

Comment: It's about how I finally resolved it. Indeed sentence lengths was used + I grouped by max size per bucket then iterated the buckets from end to start and compared bucket sizes, thus in one pass I achieved the goal without too many hassles.

Answer (score 0):

So say you have to fit a large number of items *(let's say 327 items)* into a max bucket size *(let's say 12 items per bucket)* right? You want every bucket size to be the same length after filling but bucket length not to exceed max bucket size

Get the greatest common denominator of the max bucket size and the number of items: Then that's how many items you can fit in each bucket:

```
from math import gcd
from random import shuffle

no_items = 327
max_bucket_size = 12

items_per_bucket = gcd(len(items), max_bucket_size)

list(range(327))
shuffle(items)

print(list((zip(*[iter(items)]*items_per_bucket))))
```

---

```
[(38, 273, 165),
 (212, 259, 197),
 (4, 181, 43),
 (162, 137, 23),
 (42, 146, 315),
 (99, 240, 292),
 (96, 182, 89),
 (102, 164, 73),
 (153, 248, 5),
 (84, 48, 81),
 (148, 214, 321),
 (130, 44, 40),
 (210, 312, 202),
 (127, 126, 31),
 (83, 9, 7),
 (284, 57, 194),
 (303, 109, 95),
 (223, 238, 227),
 (104, 10, 94),
 (78, 155, 224),
 (125, 271, 279),
 (123, 189, 135),
 (249, 290, 243),
 (141, 139, 119),
 (59, 311, 299),
 (186, 289, 306),
 (174, 241, 278),
 (75, 11, 286),
 (62, 228, 250),
 (169, 16, 314),
 (281, 63, 263),
 (265, 132, 108),
 (287, 129, 138),
 (177, 103, 142),
 (22, 230, 173),
 (203, 319, 239),
 (72, 180, 64),
 (47, 205, 0),
 (178, 255, 234),
 (274, 71, 117),
 (305, 316, 6),
 (301, 80, 118),
 (200, 86, 45),
 (163, 258, 147),
 (27, 232, 209),
 (183, 17, 157),
 (56, 302, 121),
 (156, 225, 3),
 (26, 282, 2),
 (150, 300, 53),
 (76, 207, 215),
 (152, 206, 74),
 (198, 28, 247),
 (51, 87, 12),
 (98, 19, 20),
 (172, 116, 298),
 (270, 195, 41),
 (188, 18, 256),
 (233, 226, 187),
 (134, 262, 309),
 (179, 190, 237),
 (317, 113, 69),
 (313, 34, 199),
 (35, 253, 159),
 (269, 308, 213),
 (295, 168, 285),
 (176, 54, 46),
 (242, 140, 100),
 (288, 191, 244),
 (219, 280, 193),
 (260, 307, 235),
 (320, 196, 264),
 (115, 277, 60),
 (33, 110, 158),
 (55, 24, 166),
 (236, 204, 293),
 (88, 120, 101),
 (32, 322, 149),
 (296, 97, 68),
 (79, 52, 14),
 (15, 29, 222),
 (58, 8, 201),
 (128, 272, 275),
 (112, 208, 283),
 (246, 220, 254),
 (111, 325, 324),
 (114, 304, 124),
 (131, 92, 39),
 (21, 1, 67),
 (323, 184, 245),
 (160, 171, 151),
 (77, 192, 268),
 (266, 136, 133),
 (291, 65, 30),
 (252, 276, 37),
 (49, 70, 50),
 (267, 13, 217),
 (170, 82, 211),
 (221, 216, 144),
 (310, 93, 25),
 (326, 106, 218),
 (318, 66, 294),
 (167, 154, 36),
 (185, 161, 107),
 (143, 145, 261),
 (61, 231, 297),
 (85, 257, 229),
 (175, 105, 90),
 (122, 251, 91)]
>
```

Comment: Not as simple, since sentences are of varying lengthes and should not be split.

Comment: I gave an answer based on the information OP gave. I mean it is a solution just hoping this is what they want.

Comment: @rubmz. do this bro : get the string len ... find the factors of string len .. then it's up to you how many buckets you want if you want more buckets then divide my min factor , if you want less buckets divide it by max factor. and please add example

Comment: @rubmz So you want every bucket size to be the same length after filling but length not to exceed max bucket size?

Comment: yes @jab  .. I guess sooo .. no clear exp. given neither he wants to  share an example we can assume currently even bucket size

Comment: Added an example. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: It looks like a kind of generalization of the knapsack problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: Could be, but I'm not sure Knapsack problem is about keeping the order of the objects/words + I am trying to optimise thedistribution and not the maximize the bucket size.

Comment: @rubmz see my edit